# In the low-quality queue, make it more clear that the canned comments are just that

Tags: feature-request, review, user-interface, low-quality-posts, automatic-comments

I often see that reviewers (including experienced ones) do one of the following when choosing the *delete* option for answers in the low-quality queue:

- They choose a canned comment, even though an existing, manual comment (usually by the flagger) precisely explains what is wrong with the post and provides better guidance to the asker than any canned comment does.

  This is bad because the author receives multiple comments telling them that their answer is unwanted, which is more likely to unnecessarily disgruntle them. Moreover, the canned comment may not be entirely consistent with the individual one, which is confusing.
- They choose the closest canned comment they can find, even though none of the canned comments is a good choice, e.g., when an answer does not address the question at all, they choose the reason intended for comments left as answers, because it begins with “this does not answer the question”, even though the post would not be a good comment at all.

  This is bad because the author of the answer and other readers are misinformed about how the things work or are intended. In the above example, the canned comment suggests that all sorts of crap is fine as a comment.

Can we therefore please make it more clear to the reviewers that the canned-comment dialogue just offers canned comments and that the chosen option has no further effect on how the post is handled? I know that the dialogue implies this, but either this message is not clear enough or not prominent enough.

This problem has also been noticed [here](https://meta.superuser.com/q/10786/203639).

Comment: Do you have any suggestions how to best make that more clear?

Comment: I've also had several users tell me "oh, you mean those are just comments? I thought it did some kind of stat collecting or sorting in the background.".

Answer (score 22):

As a possible solution, I propose to do the following two things:

- Add a description to *No comment needed* like:

  > This is a good choice if an existing comment already addresses the post’s issues.
- Add a field *Other,* allowing the reviewer to enter a custom comment, which is a regular comment, possibly with the *[from review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309704/2127008)* note.