# Why are these zombie tags on Meta SE not yet deleted by the daily cleanup script?

Tags: bug, tags, tag-pruning

I noticed that the tags [canned-comments](/questions/tagged/canned-comments) and [impact](/questions/tagged/impact) here on Meta SE are still around even though they are not associated with any questions for (apparently) quite a long time. Based on [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/960536/questions-which-no-longer-have-the-given-tag-but-had-it-at-some-point), it seems that

- the last instance of [canned-comments] was removed from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299927/313042) on [2017-12-28](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/299927/2), and
- the last instance of [impact] was removed removed from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305316/313042) on [2018-12-09](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/305316/3).

According to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753/313042), tags that are not associated to any questions ("zombie tags") are automatically deleted by a script that runs daily. So, why have these two tags survived this long?

I'll note that there don't appear to be any synonyms linked to either of these two tags. It is known that if a tag is a synonym of a master tag that is cleaned up for lack of any associated questions, then only the master tag is removed while the synonym remains behind (see [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317928/313042)). The [gaming-se](/questions/tagged/gaming-se) tag here on Meta SE is an example of such a tag, since it is synonymized with [arqade](/questions/tagged/arqade), a tag that is now removed.

But, the situation with [canned-comments] and [impact] seems to be different. Surely the daily tag cleanup script runs on Meta SE as well, so how have these two tags survived (and can we delete them)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like those tags are part of a pending synonym request:

- [impact](/questions/tagged/impact) is suggested as a [people-reached](/questions/tagged/people-reached) synonym: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/people-reached/synonyms
- [canned-comments](/questions/tagged/canned-comments) is suggested as a synonym of [automatic-comments](/questions/tagged/automatic-comments): https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/automatic-comments/synonyms.

I don't think that *should* block them from being removed by the tag Roomba, but apparently it does.

Comment: Oh! So, the script doesn't run on tags that have pending synonym requests. Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: Until your question, I didn't know about it either (and I don't think it should). I just had a hunch and it *appears* to be right...

Comment: Hm, there's a few pending. We'll take a look when time permits and try to work through that backlog.

Comment: It looks like [impact] has now been synonymized.

Comment: It looks like [canned-comments] has now been cleaned up.